# I'm having trouble installing python library, 'pip install beautifulsoap4'

Tags: python

I'm having trouble installing Python.

Here are the problems I'm having:

1. I need to install beautifulsoap4 I can not access the script directory in python.
   C From the drive, enter user-> ASUS-> python-> Nothing.
2. When you enter the pip command in anaconda, I get an error message

```
(C: \ Users \ Asus \ Anaconda3) C: \ Users \ Asus> pip install beautifulsoap4 
Collecting beautifulsoap4    
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beautifulsoap4 (from versions:) 
No matching distribution found for beautifulsoap4
```

How should I solve it?

My python version is Python 3.6.1 : Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit) which I find on Anaconda Prompt when I enter python -v code to here.

Comment: It's `beautifulsoup4` not `beautifulsoap4`

Comment: Seems to be an incorrect closure, since this was just a typoe (reading?) failure on the OPs part.